# Have parameter in Function settings still getting Not found issue at Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

I have deployed one azure function but getting below error -

> The function runtime is unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus:
>   Value for the connection string parameter name
>   '$(MyDemoConnectionString)' was not found

When I checked into setting using portal. I have this `MyDemoConnectionString` there with value still getting the above error.

I tried to restart and even delete and re-deploy still the same issue. any clue?

see below screenshot connectionstring is taken from keyvault and checked it is present and even here in settings `Key vault Reference is green`.

[image]

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the settings

Comment: updated question with screenshots

Comment: check your function version in project level and azure. If I remember correctly, I saw similar error when I was deploying azure fucntion v1 and my function instance was default configured for version 2.

Comment: host.json shows `{
  "version": "2.0"
}`  and my functionApp is also .netcore 2.0

Comment: Seems you are taking connection string from KeyValue, Did you try direct connectionString instead of KeyValult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your app should have access you can setup using Managed Service Identity

You can read from Use Key Vault references for [**`App Service and Azure Functions`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references)